# How to add a string representing a time to a moment object with just a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a moment object that contains just a date and I have a string representing a time like this

> ex. "6:00 PM" , "10:00 AM"

How can I add this time to the moment and get a new moment with both the date and time?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just using moment objects, but getting the duration out of the time string is a little ugly. But after that it's a simple matter of using `moment.add` to add your time to the date:

```js
const date = moment("2017-12-20", "YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(date.format("MMM Mo, YYYY h:mm a"))

const time = moment.duration(moment("6:00 PM", "h:mm A").format("HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(time) // This is a ISO 8601 duration string

const datetime = date.add(time)
console.log(datetime.format("MMM Mo, YYYY h:mm a"))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply format your `moment` object to string and concatenate date part with your string time part and reinitialize this string again to `moment` object.

```
// assume this is your moment object that you had already.
let date = moment('2017-12-05');

// converting it to string
let dateStr = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

let timeStr = '10:00 AM'
let dateWithTimeStr = dateStr + ' ' + timeStr;

// reinitialize date to moment again.
let dateWithTime = moment(dateWithTimeStr);
```

Comment: I'm trying this 'moment('2017-12-21' + '  ' + '10:00 PM').format(); and I'm getting invalid date'

Comment: Maybe you haven't space between date and time, try `moment('2017-12-21' + '  ' + '10:00 PM').format()`.

Comment: I do it just didn't show correctly when I pasted it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a moment instance from a particular time, and use getters to extract the time information. Then you can use setters to adjust the other instance of moment accordingly:

```
const d1 = moment('10:00AM', 'h:ma')
const d2 = moment()

console.log(d2.format('h:mm:ss a')) // "5:10:31 pm"

d2.set({
  hour: d1.hours(),
  minute: d1.minutes(),
  second: d1.seconds()
})

console.log(d2.format('h:mm:ss a')) // "10:00:00 am"
```

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: I have a previous moment with the date so I tried this moment(prevDate.format() + ' ' + '10:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD h:ma').format(); and it seemed to work I think

Comment: That works as well. Personally, I prefer the getters/setters over string concatenation, but that's just me. The moment methods exist for you to do this type of thing, so why not use them!